# Facebook App redirection

Tags: php, facebook, api

I'm new to Facebook API. Upon reading the developers page, there are 3 types of apps to choose from. I'm trying to create something very similar to Dailymotion app whereas when the user watched a video on dailymotion, it is automatically posted on their wall.

I know the basics of authentication, what I would want to know is how to start doing this app. I found the dailymotion app and whenever I try to go to it, it just redirects to their homepage (how was it done by the way? clicking the 'go to app' button leads to their site).

here's the app: http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=96937694899&ref=ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out how to do it. In facebook app page, you must uncheck everything under: "Select how your app integrates with Facebook" - Thats how I set it and when you click the app, it just redirects to the homepage and not an iframe FB app.

Regarding the "*_* watched a video on Dailymotion". Those are actions and objects using open graph as stated by Dhiraj.